# Looping through multiple items in select statement - Pandas

Tags: pandas, psycopg2

I am trying to loop through every item in a list into a SQL

```
items = ['item1','item2']

for i in items:
    print(i)
    cursor.execute(f"""select col_a, col_b, {i}, count(*)
                    from table
                    group by col_a, col_b, {i}""")
    df = cursor.fetchall()
```

The above returns an error

```
InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

I know it is to do with the variable pass in the select statement

Comment: why are you looping? why not just pass in the list of items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing core wrong with your code.  But you have used an `SQL` reserved word for your table name.  Below works as I've called it *atable*

```
items = ['item1','item2']
temptable = "atable"
for i in items:
    print(i)
    cursor.execute(f"""select col_a, col_b, {i}, count(*)
                    from {temptable}
                    group by col_a, col_b, {i}""")
    df = cursor.fetchall()
    print(df)
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```